# vm.prank is not chaging the msg.sender

Tags: solidity, foundry

```
function testDeposit() public {
      vm.prank(0x30bE4D758d86cfb1Ae74Ae698f2CF4BA7dC8d693);
      assertGt(punks.balanceOf(myAddress), 1);
      assertEq(punks.ownerOf(4), myAddress);
      // assertNotEq(address(Storage), address(0));
      emit log_named_address("Current address of sender", msg.sender);
      punks.approve(address(Storage), 4);
      // Storage.depositNft(address(punks), 4, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Please share the code for the vm.prank function first. Based on my understanding, the ```vm``` prefix in ```vm.prank``` is not a standard Solidity keyword or library. Therefore I guess it's likely a custom function that you have created and defined elsewhere in your contract.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could have whatever library or interface called “vm”, what’s non standard in this? Here, this is part of Forge vm, which is an interface to a cheat codes contract https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/

Answer (score 5):

The prank() cheat code in Foundry pranks the sender of the next call (and only the next call), all your subsequent calls (ownerOf, approve) are back to the original context, including msg.sender.

You might either use startPrank(address) and stopPrank around the whole logic, or repeat prank() before every call.

Source:  https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/start-prank

Comment: i tried the start prank first but its not visible in Contract Vm, I think I need to update foundry

Comment: This is weird, did you use the correct case, ie lower camelcase ( `vm.startPrank(address)` )?

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. vm.prank(address) sets msg.sender=address only for next "call". The call does not include a console.log statement.